# http errors - page processing

Tags: php, http-headers

If I set a http header to a 404, will the page then stop processing?  It seems that way on one server but on another it continues to process what's on the page.  I would prefer to have it continue to process so that I can provide further error messaging on the page.  Is it a setting on the server perhaps?

Comment: Ok, Ive not given a good example.  Its not just 404 pages, its any error page ie. 400's and 500's.  If I set my header to any error code it seems to stop running the page.  I want to set the header and then display an error message but it seems when it receives the header the page stops running and never displays the error message.

Comment: In fact please see my other post for more in depth example and showing the code.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653978/php-rest-api-http-headers-error-handling

Answer (score 4):

When you raise a 404 error, the page doesn't stop processing. Except if you ask it explicitly.

Simple non-technical example: If the page stopped processing, there wouldn't be sites with a custom 404 page. :)

Answer (score 1):

The page will still process, otherwise custom 404 pages woundn't be possible.  Make sure you have error reporting turned on, as you may have a PHP error that's causing the script to stop running before the page is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can set your 404 page in apache. This page should be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with CURL.  Thanks for your help.